# jQuery code doubling up action when activated twice

Tags: jquery, css, append, this, attr

I'm having an issue with some code I have programmed. The idea is to create a custom 'lightbox' using jQuery. When I click on a thumbnail, the code looks through the div which has the attributes "data-first-img-url", "data-second-img-url" and "data-third-img-url" - these attributes contain urls which become the background image of a pop up gallery.

HOEVER, the issue I'm having is that when I close the pop up and click to reopen it, the images are now there twice.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('.gallery').click(function() {
$('#overlay').fadeIn().append('<div class="main_image"></div><div class="second_image"></div><div class="third_image"></div>');
$main_img_url = $(this).attr('data-first-img-url');
$second_img_url = $(this).attr('data-second-img-url');
$third_img_url = $(this).attr('data-third-img-url');

$('.main_image').css("background-image", "url('" + $main_img_url + "')");
$('.second_image').css("background-image", "url('" + $second_img_url + "')");
$('.third_image').css("background-image", "url('" + $third_img_url + "')");

});

$(".close_gallery").click(function() {
$('#overlay').fadeOut();

});
```

And a JSfiddle (simplified) here: http://jsfiddle.net/9d9sz/3/

You can see that when you click on an image once it works fine, but then close the pop up and re-open and it's there twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you are adding a new image everytime you are opening it, remove them before you add a new one

```
$('.gallery').click(function() {
    $('.main_image').remove();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/9d9sz/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Your fading in, but each time your appending the html back to the page.

Create the div on the page and make it style="display:none;" then in your click funcs all you need to do is reference the div and fade it in.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are appending the div twice, without removing it on close.

Try:

```
$('#overlay').find('.main_image').remove().end().fadeIn().append('<div class="main_image"></div><div class="second_image"></div><div class="third_image"></div>');
```

But probably better than adding and removing DOM elements all the time would be to have it there all the time and hide/show when needed.